# Variance and expectation of dot product

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, variance, expected-value, stochastic-processes

I am wondering what is the $E[\textbf{a}\cdot \textbf{b}]$ and $var[\textbf{a}\cdot \textbf{b}]$
where $\textbf{a}, \textbf{b}$ are independent random vectors. That is as a vector whose elements are random variables. There are n elemetns in the vector. Each element in vector is assumed to be random sample from a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^{2}=1/n$. and $\cdot$ denotes dot product.

I read somewhere that 
\begin{equation}
   \begin{aligned}
   E(\tilde{\textbf{a}}\cdot \tilde{\textbf{b}})&=E(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} b_{i})\\
   &= n E(XY)= 0
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
   \begin{aligned}
   var(\tilde{\textbf{a}}\cdot \tilde{\textbf{b}})&=var(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} b_{i})\\
   &=n~var(XY) \\
   &=\dfrac{1}{n}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

How we can say $var(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} b_{i})
   =n~var(XY)$ or $E(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} b_{i})
   =n~E(XY)$. Does anyone have an idea on this?

Comment: I think that [the Matrix Cookbook](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~welling/teaching/KernelsICS273B/MatrixCookBook.pdf) will help you out here, specifically the section on `General Statistics and Probability`

Comment: Are you familiar with properties of expectation?  The relevant one is *linearity*.  This is not a matrix problem--it requires only the most straightforward application of linearity.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @whuber. I am familiar with properties of expectation more or less,  but I was not sure that is correct: $var(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} b_{i})=E((\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} b_{i})^{2})- (E(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} b_{i}))^{2} =n(E((XY)^{2})-(E(XY))^{2})$. It shouldn't be $n^{2} (E((XY)^{2})-(E(XY))^{2})$?

Comment: I have provided proof here: https://github.com/BAI-Yeqi/Statistical-Properties-of-Dot-Product/blob/master/proof.pdf :)

Comment: **a.b** will be a scalar value. How does it make sense to get the mean and variance of a scalar? Sorry for dumb question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{equation}
   \begin{aligned}
  E(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} b_{i})
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}E( a_{i} b_{i}) \text{, due to linearity}\\
   &= n E(XY) \text{ , due to i.i.d}\\
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Note that variance of sum of independent variables is equal to the sum of their variance. 
\begin{equation}
   \begin{aligned}
var(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} b_{i})
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}var( a_{i} b_{i}) \\
   &=n~var(XY) \text{, due to i.i.d}\\
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Here $X,Y$ are independent are follows distribution $N(0,\sigma^2)$. You will have to use the property that $X$ and $Y$ are independent to evalute $E(XY)$ and $var(XY)$.

Comment: How should be $var(\sum_{x} (\sum_{i}  a_{x-i}b_{i} \cdot \sum_{i'} a_{x-i'}c_{i'}))$? this is not correct $n^{3}var(X^{2}YZ)$, am I right?

Comment: where does $c$ come from?

Comment: Oh,I forgot to write, $\textbf{c}, \textbf{a},\textbf{b} $ are independent random vectors. It is another equation that I want to know its variance.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh hey could you please explain the second step in expectation for which the reason is i.i.d ? Thanks

Comment: $E(a_1b_1)=E(a_2b_2) = \ldots=E(a_nb_n)=E(XY)$, then we sum them up.